# Error in installing a python software from git-hub

Tags: python-3.x, cython

```
/home/ritika/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
  ^~~~~~~
sklearn/svm/libsvm.c: In function ‘__Pyx_GetException’:
sklearn/svm/libsvm.c:10680:24: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_type’; did you mean ‘curexc_type’?
     tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                        ^~~~~~~~
                        curexc_type
sklearn/svm/libsvm.c:10681:25: error: ‘PyThreadState {aka struct _ts}’ has no member named ‘exc_value’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
     tmp_value = tstate->exc_value;
                         ^~~~~~~~~
                         curexc_value
```

I've installed-
 sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev

Comment: This looks like [a bug/incompatibility that was fixed in Cython 2 years ago](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1955). I'd suggest you upgrade Cython (or at very least tell us something about the version you're using, or even what you're trying to install)

Comment: Cython version 0.29.16  Python Version 3.7  Os- ubuntu 18.04  . I'm trying to install a python module that automatically summarizes text documents and web pages.- [https://github.com/jaijuneja/PyTLDR] @DavidW